Is there any text that deals with conversion of aksharas to numbers? Does each aksharas have a number assigned to it? I was listening to a pravachanam
For example chanting 3 times Rama is equal to 1000 names of Vishnu. The reason given is Ra and Ma in Rama represent 2 and 5 so saying Rama 3 times results 25252*5
